# How do I get my menus back after my host moved my domain to another server?

Tags: wordpress, menu, migration

My host moved my Wordpress sites to another server without regard for my civicrm implementation, in the process they changed the directory path for the website also. I have got the site working again by updating the civicrm.settings.php with the new path settings, and the public site is working again (and seems to be able to process donations also).

But the civicrm menus are not displaying on the back end at all. I can administer the civicrm settings by following links from the admin dashboard and have cleared the caches, updated directories and checked Resource URLs.

The implementation was at 5.22.0 at migration, I have upgraded now to 5.26.2 hoping that would fix the issue but it hasn't.

How do I get my civicrm menus back?

Comment: not saying this is the answer but ... In order to rebuild the civicrm menu you can simply hit this url <your_site_name>/civicrm/menu/rebuild

Comment: also clear out templates_c or use the clear cache setting under Administer > System Settings